# PHP - get JSON array name from nested JSON (first line)

Tags: php, arrays, json

Sorry, brand new to JSON, need some help.

I receive the following JSON array as a result from my API and need to get the very first string of numbers (= entity ID), which just so happens to not be a key or value. How can I get only that number in PHP while ignoring everything else?

Result:

```
"aa7a5d31-6114-47b5-a30c-27ad724cf212"{  // <-- this is what I need
   "statusCode":200,
   "effectiveUri":"https:\/\/workmail.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
   "headers":{
      "x-amzn-requestid":"long-number-code",
      "content-type":"application\/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length":"49",
      "date":"Mon, 28 Jun 2021 13:46:18 GMT"
   },
   "transferStats":{
      "http":[
         [
            
         ]
      ]
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: That isn't valid JSON - try it at https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Sadly not much I can do about it, that's the data that comes back and I have to deal with -.-

Comment: Whoever did it like that needs to fix it - have given a bodge for an answer however

Comment: If you were told that you would _get_ JSON, then the appropriate way of “dealing” with this is to reject it with an error message or exception or something, after the attempt to decode it as JSON failed.

Comment: New to JSON, but very experience in judging the guilty ;) Nope, this is the response I get from my API call, although I am sure there is a roundabout way to get that ID via 2 more calls, which is inefficient to say the least.

Comment: You do say "ITS YOUR API" so did you create the JSON using `json_encode()` on a object or array? Or did you try and hand crank a string to be valid JSON

Comment: Its my API call, I did not "write" the API. As I said, this is the result I got back, I am using `json_encode` which returns the output I posted in my question. I can't help it if it identified as JSON but technically isn't, I just need to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = '"aa7a5d31-6114-47b5-a30c-27ad724cf212"{
   "statusCode":200,
   "effectiveUri":"https:\/\/workmail.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
   "headers":{
      "x-amzn-requestid":"long-number-code",
      "content-type":"application\/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length":"49",
      "date":"Mon, 28 Jun 2021 13:46:18 GMT"
   },
   "transferStats":{
      "http":[
         [
            
         ]
      ]
   }
}';

$result = str_replace('"','',explode("{",$json)[0]);
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression:

```
$json = '"aa7a5d31-6114-47b5-a30c-27ad724cf212"{
   "statusCode":200,
   "effectiveUri":"https:\/\/workmail.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",
   "headers":{
      "x-amzn-requestid":"long-number-code",
      "content-type":"application\/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length":"49",
      "date":"Mon, 28 Jun 2021 13:46:18 GMT"
   },
   "transferStats":{
      "http":[
         [
            
         ]
      ]
   }
}';

preg_match('/^"(.*?)"/', $json, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```